# Simple Image Gallery using Javascript for PhoneGap Android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Can anyone guide me with the simple javascript code for creating an image gallery .

I found many but integrating with my app is creating many problems, so i want it to be simple.  Should be able to flick the images back and front that is all .

Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sample web app:

[Mobile image gallery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/27/awesome-mobile-image-gallery-web-app/)

PhotoSwipe lib- http://www.photoswipe.com/

Comment: I am providing the target option as {target:'divid'} i am getting an error as "Code.PhotoSwipe.activateInstance: Unable to active instance as another instance is already active for this target at undefined:0"

please guide me how to load the gallery inside a div with id as 'divid'....

Answer (score 1):

I am using photoswipe on my android app. I may not give you the answer straight away but I have to say photoswipe is giving me a very hard time for my phonegap app on android. It does not work very well on some of android device like HTC and Note.